# KeyError: 'pos_hint' -- KIVYMD Chip

Tags: python, kivymd

I tried the KivyMD Chip, however, the following error was appear as follow:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp

class MyApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):

        return Builder.load_string(KV)

KV = '''

MDBoxLayout:
    pos_hint: {'center_y': 1, 'center_x':1}  
    
    MDChip:
        text: 'Google'
        icon: 'Google'
        check: True
'''

MyApp().run()
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\Users\Kelvin Loh\Documents\kivyMD\chip_1.py", line 18, in <module>
     MyApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\Kelvin Loh\Documents\kivyMD\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 949, in run
     self._run_prepare()
   File "C:\Users\Kelvin Loh\Documents\kivyMD\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 919, in _run_prepare
     root = self.build()
   File "c:\Users\Kelvin Loh\Documents\kivyMD\chip_1.py", line 6, in build
     return Builder.load_string(KV)
   File "C:\Users\Kelvin Loh\Documents\kivyMD\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 408, in load_string
     self._apply_rule(
   File "C:\Users\Kelvin Loh\Documents\kivyMD\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 661, in _apply_rule
     child.apply_class_lang_rules(
   File "C:\Users\Kelvin Loh\Documents\kivyMD\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 463, in apply_class_lang_rules
     Builder.apply(
   File "C:\Users\Kelvin Loh\Documents\kivyMD\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 541, in apply
     self._apply_rule(
   File "C:\Users\Kelvin Loh\Documents\kivyMD\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 663, in _apply_rule
     self._apply_rule(
   File "C:\Users\Kelvin Loh\Documents\kivyMD\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 660, in _apply_rule
     widget.add_widget(child)
   File "C:\Users\Kelvin Loh\Documents\kivyMD\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\floatlayout.py", line 135, in add_widget
     widget.bind(
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 429, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.bind
 KeyError: 'pos_hint'
```

Comment: Found no problem running your code. Make sure everything is properly installed.